# Char Arrays code in C Programming Book example not working

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-errors

I'm working on Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie's *C Programming Language 2nd Edition*, and the code provided on 1.9, on character arrays, isn't working for me. I'm sure it's not a problem with the book, so I must be missing something. But I can't figure out what. My linter is not giving me any errors, but when I try to compile it, I get a bunch of errors.

Errors:

```
scratch.c:4:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(char line[], int maxline);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:365:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
        ^
scratch.c:15:40: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
                  ~~~~~~~              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:365:9: note: 'getline' declared here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
        ^
scratch.c:26:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:365:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
```

my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main() {
    int len; 
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: `getline` is a method in the C standard library. Rename your `getline` to be something else, e.g. `getLine`.

Comment: If you are using the compilers gcc or clang, you can compile with `-std=c89` to prevent POSIX functions (such as [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3p.html)) from being declared when you `#include <stdio.h>`. That way, only functions defined by ISO C will be declared and your posted code should work, but you may get a warning for writing `int main()` instead of `int main(void)`. Note that I only recommend using `-std=c89` when using the old K&R book. For modern ISO C, I recommend using `-std=c18` instead.

Comment: In case `i<lim-1` is false then `if (c == '\n')` gets executed with an unspecified value for `c`. You should init `int c=0;`. And yeah that's probably not a bug by you but by the K&R crap book.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your program uses the identifier `getline`.

The ISO C standard (any edition) does *not* define `getline`, but POSIX does -- and POSIX (a secondary standard) specifies that the `getline` function is declared in `<stdio.h>`, one of the standard headers defined by the ISO C standard.

This is IMHO unfortunate, but it's the way it is.

Many C compilers are not conforming by default. gcc and clang (you're likely using the latter) support a number of extensions unless you tell them not to, including functions defined by POSIX.

You can compile with `-std=c90` to ask the compiler to conform to the 1990 ISO C standard (the version of the standard used by the book you're using); `-std=c89` and `-ansi` are equivalent. Or you can ask it to conform to a later standard: `-std=c99`, or `-std=c11`, or `-std-c17`. (These options still don't *fully* conform to the named C standard; you need to add `-pedantic` for that, to get all required diagnostics.)

The details may differ if you're using a different compiler. C compilers on Unix-like systems tend to try to mimic gcc's behavior, but for example Microsoft's compiler does not. Consult your compiler's documentation if necessary.

Another option is to change your function's name from `getline` to something else, like `get_line`, which is not reserved.

Answer (score 0):

> I must be missing something. But I can't figure out what.

As others have commented, the problem is that the book you are following is *really old*.

After it has been published, a standard `getline` routine has been introduced, and your (or the book's) `getline` conflicts with the standard one.

Renaming `getline` to e.g. `my_getline` in your source is the easiest solution.

Using a newer book is another possibility.

Comment: `getline` is defined by POSIX, but not by the ISO C standard. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75819309/827263).

Comment: The book is not just old, it is bad. `int c;` ... `for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())...` ... `if (c == '\n')` was always a bug in any version of C. Which could have been avoided by not writing code as if preparing for the International Obfuscated C Code Contest...